# Use Keras model with Flatten layer inside OpenCV 3

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I use Keras with TensorFlow as a backend to create and train a simple CNN.
I am able to save the model and its weights in a .pb file, freeze it and optimize it for inference but when I try to load it into OpenCV 3.4.1 I get the error:

```
flatten/Shape:Shape(max_pooling2d/MaxPool)
T:0
out_type:[ ]
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Unspecified error (Unknown layer type Shape in op flatten/Shape) in populateNet, file /home/dev/opencv-3.4.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp, line 1582
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 67, in <module>
    net = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('graph.pb')
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /home/dev/opencv-3.4.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:1582: error: (-2) Unknown layer type Shape in op flatten/Shape in function populateNet
```

This is basically the same problem as the other question: [How to import TensorFlow model with flatten layer in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127178/how-to-import-tensorflow-model-with-flatten-layer-in-opencv).

The reason for the error is pretty well explained in this thread.
The proposed workaround is to use directly `tf.reshape` instead of using the Keras API.

However I don't know exactly how to do this.
I tried to use the functional API and replace:

```
x = Flatten()(x)
```

by:

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, some_value])
```

but this doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 57, in <module>
    tf_out = model.predict(inp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 965, in predict
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 578, in build
    self.model = Model(self.inputs, self.outputs[0], name=self.name + '_model')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 678, in __init__
    super(Network, self).__init__(inputs, outputs, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/network.py", line 341, in __init__
    '(thus holding past layer metadata). Found: ' + str(x))
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("activation_4/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Any idea of how I can export a TensorFlow model while still using Keras for most of the work?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem .finally after searching a lot and testing many solutions ,
i could to import keras classification trained model in opencv.
Firstly you must to replace keras with tensorflow.python.keras.
Just remove keras from your code lines and replace it with tensorflow.python.keras
Secondly you must to replace flatten layares with this codes :
just remove flatten layers and copy and past this:

```
a,b,c,d = model.output_shape
a = b*c*d
model.add(K.layers.Permute([1, 2, 3]))  # Indicate NHWC data layout
model.add(K.layers.Reshape((a,)))
```

Now you can retrain your model.
After training finished , save your model in .h5 format.
Now you must convert keras .h5 model to tensorflow .pb model.
In order to converting models i used this workaround :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386325/5208522
Now you can easily import .pb model in opencv and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a work-around for my problem. The idea is to declare the model using Keras, convert it into a protobuf graph definition using the TensorFlow API and then dive into the generated graph definition to remove the unsupported nodes.

I encapsulated everything into the following python file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core import framework


def find_all_nodes(graph_def, **kwargs):
    for node in graph_def.node:
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if getattr(node, key) != value:
                break
        else:
            yield node
    raise StopIteration


def find_node(graph_def, **kwargs):
    try:
        return next(find_all_nodes(graph_def, **kwargs))
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError(
            'no node with attributes: {}'.format(
                ', '.join("'{}': {}".format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())))


def walk_node_ancestors(graph_def, node_def, exclude=set()):
    openlist = list(node_def.input)
    closelist = set()
    while openlist:
        name = openlist.pop()
        if name not in exclude:
            node = find_node(graph_def, name=name)
            openlist += list(node.input)
            closelist.add(name)
    return closelist


def remove_nodes_by_name(graph_def, node_names):
    for i in reversed(range(len(graph_def.node))):
        if graph_def.node[i].name in node_names:
            del graph_def.node[i]


def make_shape_node_const(node_def, tensor_values):
    node_def.op = 'Const'
    node_def.ClearField('input')
    node_def.attr.clear()
    node_def.attr['dtype'].type = framework.types_pb2.DT_INT32
    tensor = node_def.attr['value'].tensor
    tensor.dtype = framework.types_pb2.DT_INT32
    tensor.tensor_shape.dim.add()
    tensor.tensor_shape.dim[0].size = len(tensor_values)
    for value in tensor_values:
        tensor.tensor_content += value.to_bytes(4, 'little')
    output_shape = node_def.attr['_output_shapes']
    output_shape.list.shape.add()
    output_shape.list.shape[0].dim.add()
    output_shape.list.shape[0].dim[0].size = len(tensor_values)


def make_cv2_compatible(graph_def):
    # A reshape node needs a shape node as its second input to know how it
    # should reshape its input tensor.
    # When exporting a model using Keras, this shape node is computed
    # dynamically using `Shape`, `StridedSlice` and `Pack` operators.
    # Unfortunately those operators are not supported yet by the OpenCV API.
    # The goal here is to remove all those unsupported nodes and hard-code the
    # shape layer as a const tensor instead.
    for reshape_node in find_all_nodes(graph_def, op='Reshape'):

        # Get a reference to the shape node
        shape_node = find_node(graph_def, name=reshape_node.input[1])

        # Find and remove all unsupported nodes
        garbage_nodes = walk_node_ancestors(graph_def, shape_node,
                                            exclude=[reshape_node.input[0]])
        remove_nodes_by_name(graph_def, garbage_nodes)

        # Infer the shape tensor from the reshape output tensor shape
        if not '_output_shapes' in reshape_node.attr:
            raise AttributeError(
                'cannot infer the shape node value from the reshape node. '
                'Please set the `add_shapes` argument to `True` when calling '
                'the `Session.graph.as_graph_def` method.')
        output_shape = reshape_node.attr['_output_shapes'].list.shape[0]
        output_shape = [dim.size for dim in output_shape.dim]

        # Hard-code the inferred shape in the shape node
        make_shape_node_const(shape_node, output_shape[1:])
```

With this I am able to execute the following script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Reshape
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import graph_util

# Define the model in Keras
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# Get Keras prediction
inp = np.random.standard_normal([1, 28, 28, 1]).astype(np.float32)
tf_out = model.predict(inp)

# Serialize and fix the graph
sess = K.get_session()
graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)
graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph_def, [model.output.name.split(':')[0]])
graph_util.make_cv2_compatible(graph_def)

# Print the graph nodes
print('\n'.join(node.name for node in graph_def.node))

# Save the graph as a binary protobuf2 file
tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, '', 'model.pb', as_text=False)

# Get OpenCV prediction
import cv2 as cv

net = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('model.pb')
net.setInput(inp.transpose(0, 3, 1, 2))
cv_out = net.forward()

print(np.max(np.abs(tf_out - cv_out)))
```

Output is in range 1e-7, 1e-8